# How do i remove the dots in a php directory

Tags: php

I have a code that shows dots in the directory. I'm trying to get rid of them but google doesn't help, those dots mean back and localhost and the dots need to be removed how do i do this?

```
<?php
 $map = opendir('file');
 while ($bestand = readdir($map))
 {
   echo "<a href='file/$bestand'>$bestand</a><br/>"; 
 }
 closedir($map); 
?>
```

[those dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWR3z.png)

Comment: By using `if !(in_array($bestand, array(".",".."))`?

Comment: @ka_lin If it is working code please post an answer (with a few additional words what it does and why it works) instead of commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
if ($bestand == '.' || $bestand == '..')
    continue;
```

before the line contains echo

This code will skip iteration whenever $bestand is the dots.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
if(is_dir($bestand)){ continue; }
```

in the loop.
This will skip all directories and only add files.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the manual at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) and adding to HungHsuan Wei's answer.

```
<?php

if ($map = opendir('file')) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($map))) {
        if($bestand == '.' || $bestand == '..')
        continue;
    }    
    closedir($handle);
}
```